# vlc : no suitable audio output module on Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: 16.04, vlc

Vlc cannot find any audio output module on Ubuntu Xenial :

```
$ vlc --ignore-config
VLC media player 2.2.8 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.7-14-g3cc1d8cba9)
[09207cc0] core audio output error: no suitable audio output module
[09207d60] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[091e6228] core libvlc error: interface "hotkeys,none" initialization failed
[09208018] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[091e6228] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[09208018] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[091e6228] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[091e6228] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[09208018] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[091e6228] core libvlc error: interface "default" initialization failed
[0920ced0] core playlist error: could not export playlist
```

EDIT 0: My Ubuntu release :

```
$ lsb_release -sa
No LSB modules are available.
Ubuntu
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
16.04
xenial
```

Comment: you tagged release 16.10. This release is dead. `lsb_release -a`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, the version of `vlc` fits a ~16.10 release (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=vlc), where EOL releases are off-topic here - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @quiverc I had chosen the wrong tag. My Ubuntu is an LTS, please check my EDIT0